# SIEM Dashboard/Add-On/App for Viewing Windows Registry Forensics Data

Tags: windows, security, windows-registry, forensics, siem

There are a number of forensically-useful areas in the Windows registry and file system like those detailed in this SANS Poster: https://www.sans.org/security-resources/posters/windows-forensic-analysis/170/download. I'm familiar with tools like RegRipper designed to extract data from those locations and give you output.

Are there any dashboards/add-on/apps for any SIEM that allow you to interact more meaningfully with the data from a tool like RegRipper that processes data from those forensic locations (I'm interested in that data and not proprietary logging data collected by an EDR product)? I know you can view the raw output data inside of a SIEM. But I'm curious if there are ways to view that data that go beyond staring at lines in a log file.

Thanks for any suggestions or input you can share.